# Spring Security 3.2.5 - Concurrency Login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-session

After many days of research I gave up and my only hope is that here I could find my help.

I have my application that the login part is manually using Spring 4 with Spring Security 3.2.5. Now I need to control the login concurrency, but doesn't work.

My codes:

**spring-security.xml**

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" create-session="always">
    <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/protected/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <!-- Necessário jogar a pasta template para fora do protected por causa do AngularJS ( $routeProvider ) -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/template/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /> 

    <form-login login-page="/public/login"
                default-target-url="/protected/main"
                authentication-failure-url="/public/login?error=403"  
                always-use-default-target="true"/>

    <logout logout-success-url="/public/login"
            logout-url="/logout"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE"
            invalidate-session="true"/>

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/public/login" >
        <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/logout"/>
    </session-management>

    <remember-me key="rememberkysecurity" services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>

    <headers >
        <cache-control />
        <frame-options />
        <hsts/>
    </headers>
</http>

<beans:bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <beans:property name="key" value="rememberkysecurity" />
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <beans:property name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="10080" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="autenticationManagerDB" >
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" id="userDetailsService" 
                           users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM user WHERE username = ?"
                           authorities-by-username-query= "SELECT usr_id, 'ROLE_ADMIN' AS role FROM user WHERE username = ?"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>APP</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/public/login</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>360</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>false</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

**Java Login**

```
Authentication authenticatedUser = null;
    if ( keeplogged ) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername( user.getUsername() );
        RememberMeAuthenticationToken rememberMeAuthenticationToken = new RememberMeAuthenticationToken( "rememberkysecurity", userDetails, userDetails.getAuthorities() );

        rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, rememberMeAuthenticationToken);
        authenticatedUser = rememberMeAuthenticationToken;

    } else {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( user.getUsername(), user.getPassword() );

        authenticatedUser = this.autenticationManagerDB.authenticate( authenticationToken );

    }
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername( user.getUsername() );
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( authenticatedUser );
```

Comment: Just to confirm is the expected behavior that the second login should not go ahead  and show 
'Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
Reason: Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded'

Comment: What I hope is that when the second session begins, the previous session logged into another browser to be invalidated. This is because I don't want the error message

Answer (score 0):

In your session management config just put the error-if-maximum-exceeded key to true:

```
<http>
   ...
   <session-management>
      <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
   </session-management>
   ...
</http>
```

Note that by putting this key to false, the user is allowed to login but spring only invalidate the first session. Putting it at true, will just disallow user to sign in again

**UPDATE**: Take a look at this doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions

Comment: Tks kad Dembele, for me needs to be "false". But when I put "true", the error really appear for me, but when I logout the error still showing.

Comment: The problem is that the another session wasn't invalidated

Comment: This is normal, because an exeption is thrown, just take a look at this doc on hown to handle those exeptions: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions

Answer (score 0):

### Use UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Is there a reason you aren't using Spring Security's `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`? If you were this would be handled for you out of the box.

### Custom Controller

If you are providing your own controller for authentication, then you need to perform the `SessionAuthenticationStrategy` manually. Typically this is done using the `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` which is populated with the following implementations (in this order):

- **ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy** - verifies that a user is allowed to authenticate (i.e. they have not already logged into the application.
- **SessionFixationProtectionStrategy** - changes the session id on authentication to ensure a session fixation attack is not launched
- **RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy** - registers the new user as currently authenticated

So to fix your issue you should be able to do the following:

```java
@Autowired
CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy strategy;


public void doLogin() {

    Authentication authenticatedUser = null;
    if ( keeplogged ) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername( user.getUsername() );
        RememberMeAuthenticationToken rememberMeAuthenticationToken = new RememberMeAuthenticationToken( "rememberkysecurity", userDetails, userDetails.getAuthorities() );

        rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, rememberMeAuthenticationToken);
        authenticatedUser = rememberMeAuthenticationToken;

    } else {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( user.getUsername(), user.getPassword() );

        authenticatedUser = this.autenticationManagerDB.authenticate( authenticationToken );

    }
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername( user.getUsername() );

    sessionStrategy.onAuthentication(authenticatedUser, request, response);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( authenticatedUser );
}
```